# Creating scalar multiplication operator for 2d vector class

Tags: c++, class, game-physics

So I'm making a 2D vector class for a class where I create collisions between circular objects with mass and radius on a x-y plane. So everytime a collision happens, I need to update the velocity of the two circles that collided and this relies upon scalar numbers like mass and radius as well as the kinetic energy (scalar) and the momentum (2d vector) of the stones (since momentum and energy conserved , you can solve the momentum and energy of either). All the methods work except for the scalar multiplication. I will only display that method below unless you guys specifically request for me to show the others

Here's my 2d vector class

```
class vector2d {
  public:
     double x;
     double y;
     // Constructor
     vector2d() { x=0; y=0; }
     vector2d(double_x, double_y) { x=_x; y=_y;}
     .
     .
     .
     vector2d operator*(const double& scalar) const {
     return {x * scalar, y * scalar };
     }
```

Here's the method in the other class that does the updates the velocity after collision

```
void collide(Ball *s) {
  // Make sure move is called before this to update the position vector'
  vec2d diff_pos_s1 = this->init_pos - s->init_pos;
  vec2d diff_vel_s1 = this->velocity - s->velocity;
  double mass_ratio_s1 = (2 * s->mass) / (this->mass + s->mass);
  double num_s1 = diff_pos_s1.dot_product(diff_vel_s1);
  double denom_s1 = diff_pos_s1.dot_product(diff_pos_s1);
  vec2d v1 = this->velocity - (mass_ratio_s1 * (num_s1 / denom_s1) * diff_pos_s1);

  vec2d diff_pos_s2 = s->init_pos - this->init_pos;
  vec2d diff_vel_s2 = s->velocity - this->velocity;
  double mass_ratio_s2 = (2 * this->mass) / (this->mass + s->mass);
  double num_s2 = diff_vel_s2.dot_product(diff_pos_s2);
  double denom_s2 = diff_pos_s2.dot_product(diff_pos_s2);
  vec2d v2 = s->velocity - (mass_ratio_s2 * (num_s2 / denom_s2) * diff_pos_s2);

  this->velocity = v1;
  s->velocity = v2;
}
```

Here's the methods that calculate energy and momentum

```
double energy() const {
  return 0.5 * (mass * velocity * velocity) ;
}
// Calculates the momentum of the balls
vec2d momentum() const {
  return mass * velocity;
}
```

Here are the errors that are produced:

```
error: no match for 'operator*' (operand types are 'double' and 'vector2d')
error: no match for 'operator*' (operand types are 'const double' and 'vector2d')
```

Let me know if I should put more information

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? You only need to give just enough code to illustrate your overloaded operator. The `collide()` function is much more complex than necessary to illustrate this. I suggest creating a single file with your `vector2d` class and only the members necessary for your question. Also include a `main()` function to illustrate what you are trying to do. When you post the code here, anyone should be able to copy and paste it and get the exact same compiler error which you are asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code multiples a `double` to a `vector2d`. That won't activate the operator, because the operator will expect a `vector2d` first. You should have either

```
vec2d v1 = this->velocity - (diff_pos_s1 * (mass_ratio_s1 * (num_s1 / denom_s1)));
```

or write an `vector2d operator*(double, vector2d)`, for instance

```
vector2d operator *(const double & scalar, const vector2d & other) {
   return { other.x * scalar, other.y*scalar };
}
```

As an aside, it seems a waste of time to me to use a reference on a `const double`.

Comment: I tried making my operator look the one you posted before, but it would gave me the same errors as before along with an extra error of requesting for more than one argument

Comment: Don't put the new operator in the class; put it outside the class. That's almost certainly the cause of these errors.